# Caching with Redis on a Parse Server

Tags: caching, redis, parse-server

I'm on a `2.6.3` Parse Server and I need to cache the results of queries, to speed things up!

I understand that Parse Server offers a Redis adapter. What exactly do I have to do, in order to start using Redis? Are there any modules I should install? Anything I should import or configure?

Also, I found this on Parse's documentation:

> Those cache adapters can be cleaned at anytime internally, you should not use them to cache data and you should let parse-server manage their data lifecycle.

What do they mean by saying `you should not use them to cache data and you should let parse-server manage their data lifecycle.`? Should I not use the adapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What [the doc](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#configuring-cache-adapters) is saying is that parse caches with it's own in-memory structure by default, but it leaves developers the option to use reddis as a substitute.  To opt for that, just (1) setup redis as you typically would, (2) initialize the parse server with a `RedisCacheAdapter` that's been configured with your redis URL.

The point you're asking about: "you should not use them to cache data ..." means that *Parse will continue to decide when to cache, when to retrieve from cache, and when to clean*, etc. but it will do so by invoking the redis that you configured with.

I think the major advantage to this more elaborate setup is redis's distributed capability.  If you're not running on a cluster, you may find the redis idea to be about equivalent performance-wise and a little messier setup-wise as not doing it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! By `To opt for that, just (1) setup reddis as you typically would` you mean what exactly?